# view fails to update after executing ngModelController.$render function

Tags: angularjs

Refer to this code:

http://plnkr.co/edit/4QpPZZib6qGjhx85Do0M

Here's how to replicate the error:

```
1. Run the plnkr
2. then click on any of the buttons "200", "300" etc. You will notice that the model updates just fine. No issue so far
3. Now paste something in the input box. The paste should work just fine.

4. Now try clicking on any of the buttons. 

ERROR:
You will notice that the values in the input box does not updates to model value.
```

From what I can understand the issue is with my $render function.. however I can't seem to find a fix for it.

```
scope.handlePaste = function(e) {
          var pastedText = e.clipboardData.getData('text/plain');
          ngModelController.$setViewValue(pastedText);
          ngModelController.$render = function() {
              element.html($sce.getTrustedHtml(ngModelController.$viewValue));
            };

          return false; //prevent the default handler from running
        };
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You're using [ngSanitize](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngSanitize) but you forgot to include it in the plunker. (lib + injection in app and $sce in directive).

Then `element` is an angular element and doesn't have an `html()` function.
You can get the raw html element with `element[0]` which has a property `value`.

http://plnkr.co/edit/HSOnscaprbyvUwjr0P2l?p=preview